# How to switch user while still seeing the running applications in Windows 10

Tags: display, switch, user, lock

The usecase is, to switch the user during a shift change while still seeing the critical application running on the screen. OS W10.

Is there any possible/ imaginable way to achieve this?

Not speaking about the problems occurring for the running applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is impossible for a GUI window to exist simultaneously across multiple sessions.

If you're able to rewrite a large part of the app:

0. Split the app into two parts, the service and the interface.
1. Run the critical part of the application as a *system service* without any UI.
2. Have your users run the interface, which then connects to the service using some form of IPC (e.g. Windows provides "named pipes").

If rewriting the app is impossible or impractical:

1. Run the critical application on a *dedicated* machine (and under its own user account).
2. Have your users connect to that machine via RDP (MS Remote Desktop) or VNC.

Generally, remote desktop software allows detaching (disconnecting) and re-attaching, so your program will just continue running while a different user connects to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's actually a great input. They application should know that the user has changed and load its settings. (Settings of the new user.)

Comment: In that case, you will need to do something different. A running app cannot "move" from user to user – if you need it to be user-aware, then it has to be split into two parts; the per-user interface and the central "critical part".

Comment: Thanks a lot. The app is already running like that. The workstation has only UI purposes. My point of interest is that it should be possible to see the screen content at all times. But it seems, that the only approach is to have the application itself providing a logging interface.